# How to get the counter to increment in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the value of i to increment but it just seems to be repeating the value of 2 here. I thought that it should keep incrementing by 1 as I set the value to 1 right at the start but not shown here because it is near at the top of my class..

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

        String clinic_info = String.valueOf(childSnapshot.child("Name").getValue());
        String txt_review = review.getText().toString();
        String txt_dorevitch = dorevitch.getText().toString();
        String txt_skin_cancer = skin_cancer_check.getText().toString();
        String txt_ear_suctioning = ear_suctioning.getText().toString();

        message[0] = message[0].split("\\s*:\\s*")[0]; // use this to get the name of the clinic only..
        //   replace(":" ,"");
        //    message[0] = message[0].replaceAll("[0-9]" ,"");
        //   message[0] = message[0].replace("Shop" ,"");
        //
        assert clinic_info != null;
        if (clinic_info.equals(message[0])) {

            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("Review" + i, txt_review);

            i = (int)snapshot.getChildrenCount();

            i++;

            System.out.println(i);
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child(message[0]).updateChildren(map);
            Toast.makeText(Add_Review.this, "Review Successfully Submited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {


            Toast.makeText(Add_Review.this, "There was an error while updating the database, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: For some reason, it either just stops at a particular number or just get overridden...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is that you didn’t update the value of `i`. `i = i + 1` will work as you did not change the value of `i`. You can try printing `System.out.println(i++)`;

Comment: I tried that as well but the value only stopped at 3... didn't keep incrementing....

Comment: I have kind of sort a workaround it but now have another issue, which I will post separately

Comment: when I use the number to increment the counter, other users will also override it but i manage to append the username to the review name of the database